# In R, find whether two files differ

Tags: r, diff

I would like a pure R way to test whether two arbitrary files are different. So, the equivalent to `diff -q` in Unix, but should work on Windows and without external dependencies.

I'm aware of `tools::Rdiff`, but it seems to only want to deal with R output files and complains loudly if I feed it something else.

Comment: Do you want to know only if the files are different or also output the corresponding in and out changes? If only the first is true, why not write a simple function to give you a binary reponse?

Comment: just to know if they are different.

Comment: Okay. then use all.equal: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Without using memory, if the files are too large:

```
library(tools)
md5sum("file_1.txt") == md5sum("file_2.txt")
```

Comment: Hey, is tools a base package? Or do I have to install it. If not, I like this answer.

Comment: If you have order 2^64 files or if you're checking for security reasons, this may not be the solution for you.

Comment: Yes its a base package.

Answer (score 36):

the closest to the unix command is `diffr` - it shows a really nice side by side window with all the different lines marked in color.

```
library(diffr)
diffr(filename1, filename2)
```

shows

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate this answer. Most other answers fail to colorize -- which is super necessary.

Comment: For .R files: diffr("file1.R","file2.R")

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is not exactly what you're asking for, but I post it for the benefit of others who run into this question wanting to see the full diff and willing to tolerate external dependencies.  In that case, **[`diffobj`](https://github.com/brodieG/diffobj)** will show them to you with a real diff that works on windows, with the same algorithm as GNU diff.  In this example, we compare the Moby Dick text to a version of it with 5 lines modified:

```
library(diffobj)
diffFile(mob.1.txt, mob.2.txt)   # or `diffChr` if you data in R already
```

Produces:

[image]

If you want something faster while still getting the locations of the differences you can get the shortest edit script, from the same package:

```
ses(readLines(mob.1.txt), readLines(mob.2.txt))
# [1] "1127c1127"   "2435c2435"   "6417c6417"   "13919c13919"
```

---

Code to get the Moby Dick data (note I didn't set seed, so you'll get different lines):

```
moby.dick.url <- 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-0.txt'
moby.dick.raw <- moby.dick.UC <- readLines(moby.dick.url)
to.UC <- sample(length(moby.dick.raw), 5)
moby.dick.UC[to.UC] <- toupper(moby.dick.UC[to.UC])

mob.1.txt <- tempfile()
mob.2.txt <- tempfile()

writeLines(moby.dick.raw, mob.1.txt)
writeLines(moby.dick.UC, mob.2.txt)
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get this thing working for pdfs without reading them as text first?

Answer (score 3):

Example solution:
(Using all.equals utility from: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html)

```
filenameForA <- "my_file_A.txt"
filenameForB <- "my_file_B.txt"
all.equal(readLines(filenameForA), readLines(filenameForB))
```

Note, that

```
readLines(filename)
```

reads all the lines from given file specified by filename,
then all.equal can figure out if the files differ or not.

Make sure to read the documentation from above to understand fully. 
I've to admit, that if the files are very large, this might not be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

```
all.equal(readLines(f1), readLines(f2))
```