# I am trying to make a simple app to compare two R files

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the diffR function to accept two .R files to compare the differences in a shiny app.  Where someone can upload two R files and then it will utilize diffR to output.

I can run my code locally where I define my file one and file two as directories locally and then I'll get a side by side output of the code to show the differences.  It highlights differences and then adjustments can be made.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$contents <- renderPrint({
    info_old <- input$old_file

    if(is.null(info_old))
        return(null)

    df_old <- readLines(info_old$datapath)
    df_old
})

    output$new_contents <- renderPrint({


    info_new <- input$new_file
    if(is.null(info_new)){return()}

    df_new <- readLines(info_new$datapath)
    df_new
})
    output$exdiff <- renderDiffr({
        diffr(info_old(), info_new(), wordWrap = input$wordWrap,
              before = "Original_File", after = "New File")
    })
}
```

I know this simple where both the old_file and the new_file are generated side.  This stack answer shows exactly what I am looking for:

[In R, find whether two files differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081791/in-r-find-whether-two-files-differ)

Where the diffr package is used.  I just want the user to have the ability to upload the two R files so do the side by side comparison instead of defining file a and b globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the datapath given by the uploaded files: `input$files[[1, 'datapath']]`.

If you like, a small remark on your (good) attempt. The `diffr()` function demands the connection to the file not the content itself. I ran into the same trap as well. So if you remove the `readLines()` in your code you should be pretty close.

You might want to include a test, that the length of uploaded files is not smaller or greater than 2, to ensure the app doesnt crash if e.g. only one file is given.

**Reproducible example:**

```
write.csv2(
  x = "diff same", 
  file = "test.csv"
)

write.csv2(
  x = "diffhere same", 
  file = "test2.csv"
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(
        inputId = "files", 
        label = "Choose CSV File", 
        multiple = TRUE,
        accept = c("text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      diffrOutput("exdiff")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$exdiff <- renderDiffr({
    req(input$files)

    diffr(
       file1 = input$files[[1, 'datapath']], 
       file2 = input$files[[2, 'datapath']], 
       wordWrap = TRUE,
       before = "f1", 
       after = "f2"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```