# Why is it not possible to diff 2 files in sublime text 3103 on mac anymore?

Tags: macos, diff, sublimetext3

I know this feature was available previously. Selecting 2 files inside a project, right clicking them and do a diff on both files. This does not work anymore on build 3103. After selecting both files, I right click and then one file gets deselected. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Sublime Text has no native support to run diff, so I'm assuming you're using a third-party package, most likely FileDiff. Sounds like a bug, so you're better off [reporting](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs/issues) it to the author of the package!

Comment: @idleberg [au contraire](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30012550/1426065). Sublime has always had a built-in diff functionality, as it's included in the Python stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, but it only appears under certain conditions. I tested [Build 3103](http://sublimetext.com/3) (the most recent public build) and the latest dev build [3111](http://sublimetext.com/3dev) (just released today, in fact) on OS X 10.10.5. First I picked two random files in one of the folders of my project that were not already open, clicked to select one, held down <kbd>⌘</kbd> and clicked to select the other, then right-clicked on one and selected <kbd>**`Diff Files...`**</kbd>. The diff view opened up just fine in both 3103 and 3111.

*However*, if one or both of the files *was already open in Sublime*, it could not be selected in the sidebar in 3103, and therefore the Diff Files command wasn't accessible. Diffing worked just fine on open files in Build 3111.

So, if you're a registered user (and you really should be if you're using Sublime long-term or for commercial purposes), just [download](http://sublimetext.com/3dev) Build 3111 (or whatever the most recent dev build is when you read this) and you'll be all set.